# iPhone 6 suddenly lost it's "Name" (I.e. "Nancy's iPhone")

Tags: iphone

We don't know what triggered it, but the specific name of our iPhone 6 "Nancy's iPhone" suddenly lost it's "name" and became "iPhone."

Now we're having issues backing it up, as the computer doesn't recognize it (since the name is now different).  How do we change it back?

Comment: Something more has changed than just the name as iTunes will continue to recognise a device even if the name changes.

Comment: This also happened to me after I reset the network settings (to fix an issue with calls always failing).

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> General -> About -> Name